# Integrating application Yocto arm bitbake

Tags: cmake, arm, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm trying to have my recipe be compiled and linked against the arm libraries. I'm using cmake. I can't seem to figure out the right work flow, after having read trough multiple documents on the yocto site and reference materials. My approach right now is:

- Set the source
- Build my target minal image, without the layer that I want to use
- Try to build my specific recipe: bitbake Test

I have downloaded the arm toolchain from the Yocto site, and prepared it in my sources/poky. Here I can see the systroots and all the libraries that I would need. My recipe bb file is the following:

```
# This file was derived from the 'Hello World!' example recipe in the
# Yocto Project Development Manual.
#

SUMMARY = "Project"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
SRC_URI = "file://."

S = "${WORKDIR}/project/src"

inherit pkgconfig cmake externalsrc
```

And my CMake file contains, among more:

```
link_directories(/media/traffic/Yocto/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/sources/poky/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib)
```

I'm able to compile a hello world project fine, but as soon as external libraries take a role, it goes wrong.

```
cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a

/media/traffic/Yocto/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_ls2084abluebox/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fsl-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/4.9.3/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
```

It seems to look in the wrong folder. Are the steps that I'm taking correctly? Or am i missing something?

Elmar

Answer (score 1):

Which poky version are you using? I got exactly the same issue recently with another package. There are 2 issues here:

It cannot find the pThread library. I added a `FindThreads.cmake` in the tree and imported it. But then the linker could not make it. I went to the conclusion, cmake itself had an issue with this library and ended changing the poky commit to have a different version of CMake. Note that you can also keep the new poky versions and have the custom CMake in your layer.

CMake 3.7 and 3.8.2 were not working properly but the 3.7.1 was for me (hash `c9a512b6408d4cc11c1b36f7bc1b9b1c31056ce1`). To find out which commit, you can execute

`git log --pretty=oneline | grep cmake:`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am using poky distro version 2.0. I updated my CMake to the same version as you have. Did that work for you after setting the sysroot variable in CMake? Or did you have to revert to your own FindThreads.cmake file which pointed towards the sysroot/usr/lib/ ?

Comment: Was this the error you used to get with CMake?

    -- Could NOT find Threads (missing:  Threads_FOUND)
    -- Could NOT find Threads (missing:  Threads_FOUND)

Comment: Yes that's what put me on track at start to add the FindThreads.cmake